# как использувать переменные одной формы в другой?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
  public partial class EnterWidthAndHeight : Form
    {
        public EnterWidthAndHeight()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public int width_of_nonogram;
        public int height_of_nonogram;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             width_of_nonogram = int.Parse(WidthOfNonogram.ToString());
             height_of_nonogram = int.Parse(HeightOfNonogram.ToString());
            EnterColsAndRows enterColsAndRows = new EnterColsAndRows(width_of_nonogram,height_of_nonogram);
            enterColsAndRows.Show();

        }

    }
}





 public partial class EnterColsAndRows : Form
    {
        private int width_of_nonogram;
        private int height_of_nonogram;
        public EnterColsAndRows(int width,int height)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            width_of_nonogram = width;
            height_of_nonogram = height;

        }


    }
```

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне нужно использувать те же самые переменные width_of_nonogram и height_of_nonogram, а не передать даные

Comment: Ну так посмотрите внимательней на то, как там объявлена переменная или метод. Они находятся в классе формы, модификатор доступа - public. Далее для того, что бы не создавать новые переменные с новыми значениями, мы должны передать ссылку на текущую форму в другое окно (это тоже показано в том ответе). Другими словами вы должны сделать в классе EnterWidthAndHeight  две переменные (`public int width_of_nonogram;`, в другое окно передавать ссылку на EnterWidthAndHeight окно и уже работать с этой ссылкой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ   private int width_of_nonogram;
        private int height_of_nonogram;
        public EnterColsAndRows(int width,int height)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            width_of_nonogram = width;
            height_of_nonogram = height;
          
        }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала, давайте поговорим о переменных, полях, методах и др.

Допустим у нас есть некий класс:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public string FieldOne;
    private string FieldTwo;

    public void Read()
    {
        Write("Hello!");
        Console.WriteLine($"Приватное поле: {FieldTwo}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Публичное поле: {FieldOne}");
    }

    private void Write(string text)
    {
        FieldTwo = text;
    }
}
```

Что мы тут видим?

- У нас есть `public` поле (Field) к которому мы имеем доступ из всех методов нашего класса, а также из других классов которые инициализируют данный класс.
- У нас есть `private` поле (Field) к которому мы имеем доступ из всех методов нашего класса, но мы не сможем задать/получить значение данного поля извне.
- Также у нас есть два метода один `public`, а другой `private`, с ними все аналогично, `private` - доступа из вне нет, но есть доступ внутри класса; `public` - имеем доступ со всех возможных точек.

  - `public` метод Read в данном случае вызывает `private` метод Write и выводит значение двух Field на консоль.
  - `private` метод Write просто задает нашему `private` полю значение из переданного ему текста.

Теперь давайте сделаем вызов всего этого:

```
MainClass mainClass= new MainClass();
mainClass.FieldOne = "Привет землянин!";
mainClass.Read();
```

Можно заметить, что после инициализации нашего класса (`new...`) мы без труда можем работать со всеми публичными полями и методами, которые заданы в корне данного класса.

На консоль тем временем выведится:

```
Приватное поле: Hello!
Публичное поле: Привет землянин!
```

Теперь предположим у нас есть в неком классе метод:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    int MyField;
}
```

**Вопрос:** А сможем ли мы получить доступ `MyField` из других классов, методов и др.?
**Ответ:** Нет. Это локальное поле с которым может работать только данный метод!

Подведем итог:

1. Если нам требуется использовать поле за пределами метода, то следует его вынести в тело класса с указанием модификатора доступа.
2. Если мы ходим, что бы нашем полем могли воспользоваться другие классы (за пределом текущего класса), то стоит указать соответсвующий модификатор доступа (к примеру `public`).

---

Теперь поговорим о передаче значений между классами:

Создадим еще один класс, он должен уметь работать со всем, что есть у нашего `MainClass`:

```
public class MySecondClass
{
    private MainClass MainClass;

    public MySecondClass(MainClass MainClass)
    {
        MainClass = MainClass;
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        MainClass.Read();
    }
}
```

Что мы имеем?

- `private MainClass MainClass;` - Мы задаем необходимый нам объект, к которому имеет доступ все, что находится внутри текущего класса. Но он изначально null, его надо инициализировать или задать значение.
- `public MySecondClass(MainClass MainClass)` - это так называемый "конструктор", все, что внутри него будет выполнено при инициализации (то есть при `new MySecondClass();`). Конструктором мы можем принимать то, что необходимо для работы данного класса (в данном случае это другой класс).
- `MainClass = MainClass;` - При написание `new MainClass()` у нас создается объект, но что будет если мы несколько раз это пропишем? Да все просто, при каждой инициализации объекта все его внутренние значения будут изначальными (то есть те, что мы зададим, либо Null). В некоторых случаях нам нужны несколько одинаковых объектов, а в некоторых люди по ошибки создают дубликат (той же формы к примеру), когда можно воспользоваться уже созданным и передать ссылку на него. Вот в данном случае мы передаем ссылку параметром `MainClass`, которая в конструкторе передается нашему приватному `MainClass`.
- `public void Read()` - тут все просто уже становится, простой публичный метод, который вызывает публичный метод из другого класса.

Давайте перепишем немного вызов всего этого:

```
MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
MySecondClass mySecondClass = new MySecondClass(mainClass);
mainClass.FieldOne = "Привет землянин!";
mySecondClass.Read();
```

Мы инициализируем сначала наш основной класс (MainClass), затем инициализируем второй класс (MySecondClass) в который передаем ссылку на основной класс, задаем в основном классе публичному полю значение и вызываем уже из **второго** (а не из первого как раньше) класса наш метод Read. Результатом будет тот же текст.

Ну вроде все, надеюсь я помог вам этим "ликбезом", растолковал о доступности методов или полей, а также с правильной передачей значений между классами. Удачи в изучение C#!

Comment: @y47999 и? Во первых очень не удобно читать так код, а во вторых, ну вроде все нормально, в чем трудности?

Comment: да, я сделала по тому примеру, но у меня форма не загружается @ EvgeniyZ

Comment: @y47999 Ну она не может же просто так не загружаться, ошибки небось есть или еще что?

Comment: вроде бы  все нормально @EvgeniyZ

Comment: @y47999 Отлично! Рад, что разобрались. Не забудьте отметить ответ "галкой", если он вам помог.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Здравствуйте еще раз, вроде делаю все, как написали вы:
создаю приватное поле, инициализирую его, но возникают ошибки: https://ibb.co/1qmHTSW

Comment: @Бармалей А слушать вы меня так и не хотите. Ну говорю же "new MainWindows(), это создание нового окна, а не использование старого. Вы уверены, что такое поведение вам нужно?". Также почитайте про конструкторы, ну серьезно, вопросы базовые... Вы классу сделали конструктор, который теперь обязан принимать при создание ваш `ClassPlant`, где вы его задаете при инициализации?