# Взаимодействие классов. Как изменить данные в классе из другого класса?

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс в котором обьявлены массивы:

```
public  class Class1
    {

     public  string[] Names { get; set; } = new string[100];
     public int[] Age { get; set; } = new int[100];

    }
```

Во втором классе они меняются:

```
Class1 class1= new Class1();
class1.Names[0] = "Bob";
class1.Age[0] = 30;
```

В третьем они должны выводится в консоль,но ничего не выводится(как я понимаю,изменения внесенные во втором классе не видно в третьем,и он просто выводит пустые значения)

```
private Class1 Class1;
Class1  = Class1;
Console.WriteLine("{0,1}",Class1.Names[0]);
Console.WriteLine("{0,1}",Class1.Age[0]);
```

Comment: Вы купили новую машину, сделали ей тюнинг, далее купили еще одну машину, будет ли в ней этот тюнинг? Также и тут, вы везде инициализируете класс по новой, создавая совершенно чистейший, новый объект. Передавайте ссылку на уже ранее инициализированный класс, работайте с ней и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Сделайте свойства статическими, тогда все получится. Но вообще вы похоже не улавливаете разницы между классом и его экземплярами.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ,а можете подсказать,как это сделать?

Comment: Воспринимайте класс как чертеж дома или какой-то детали. Когда вы пишете `new Class1();` вы построили новый дом или выточили новую деталь по этому чертежу. У каждого типового дома свой житель, а у каждой детали свой кусок металла из которого она сделана.

Comment: @Bulson,я понял свою ошибку,но я не могу понять как можно передать данные по-другому. Буду очень благодарен если обьясните или покажете на примере

Comment: @Богдан Я как то писал такой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553), поглядите, думаю будет полезно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Попытался сделать по примеру, получаю ошибку "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." код в вопросе поменял. В чем ошибка?

Comment: @Богдан `= Class1` что это?

Comment: Ну,у Вас в примере было  MainClass = MainClass;. Я сделал так же со своим классом. Получается передал ссылку

Comment: @Богдан Да, но `= MainClass` в том примере задается через конструктор (`public MySecondClass(MainClass MainClass)`), через который в последующем и передается уже инициализированный объект. Где у вас это все?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо,разобрался. Можете добавить ответ,что бы я мог отметить его как лучший?

Comment: @Богдан Тут не отвечать надо, а дубликатом отметить.