# C# вывод элементов из публичного класса в ListBox

Tags: c#, классы, list, form, listbox

Дорогие друзья! Сразу прошу прощения за мою неопытность.
Имею две формы, в которых есть ListBox. Представим, что ListBox - содержание заказа, а две формы - блок с напитками и блок с пиццами. Я создал класс (через Проект -> добавить класс), создаю в форме с пиццами "public List order= new List()" , добавляю в класс разные пиццы, после чего вывожу в ListBox, всё прекрасно работает. Но у меня не получается вывести элементы этого класса в другой форме (с напитками), пробовал создавать такой же лист (public List order= new List()), но понимаю что он пустой, а как передать именно заполненный я не знаю

Большое спасибо за прочтение и заранее благодарю Вас!

[image: Класс]

[image: Заполняю и вывожу элементы класса]
[image: В начале формы с Пиццами инициализирую лист класса]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553

Comment: Does this answer your question? [как использувать переменные одной формы в другой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835214/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: Дорогие друзья, спасибо большое за помощь! Вскоре попробую ваши способы, пока нашёл альтернативное решение без переключений форм
Удачи Вам!

Comment: 1) можно сделать класс Static и тогда его значения будут во всех формах одни и теже 2) можно передавать экземпляр класс в конструктор формы