# Как создать условие с DialogResult

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть 2 формы: 1 - это регистрационное окно, а 2 - это основная сама программа

Мне нужно чтоб если польз нажал проско крестик (закрытие формы) не пройдя при этом регистрацию закрывалисть все формы. я это сделал, но теперь у меня получилось что даже если он и пройдет регистрацию, у меня все равно все формы закрываются, а нужно чтобы только регистрационное окно закрылось. Вот код

```csharp
if (this.DialogResult != DialogResult.OK)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Подскажите, как создать правильно условие (при клике на кнопку происходило закрытие только рег формы, а при клике на закрытие рег формы при это не регистрируясь закрывались все формы)

Comment: Вы проверяете `DialogResult`, но чтобы он менялся, надо его присвоить внутри той формы.

Comment: В диалоговой форме навесить на кнопку результат так `_buttonAdd.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` весь пример [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1094963/222542)