# Как достать переменную из конструктора формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Передаю через конструктор объект класса в форму, я могу его использовать только в Инициализации формы, а в остальных местах я его использовать не могу, как это можно исправить ?

```
 public workSpace(Class1 class1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FirstTextBox.Text = class1.getFirst();
        SecondTextBox.Text = class1.getSecond();
        ThirdTextBox.Text = class1.getThird();
    }
```

Тут код работает, но пытаюсь я вызвать что-нибудь любое из этого при нажатии на кнопку на форме, то ничего не выходит

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как использувать переменные одной формы в другой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835214/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Class1 class1;

public workSpace(Class1 class1)
{
    this.class1 = class1;
    InitializeComponent();
    FirstTextBox.Text = class1.getFirst();
    SecondTextBox.Text = class1.getSecond();
    ThirdTextBox.Text = class1.getThird();
}
```