# Проблемы с ООП в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть главный код, здесь я при нажатии на кнопку **plant1_Click** хочу создавать экземпляр класса **Plant**, присваивая ему значения **name**, **color** и **age**.

Позже я хочу изменять значение **age** из главного кода.

Так же я хочу вызывать метод **ShowInfo** в главном коде, который должен показывать значения переменных объекта класса **Plant**

Но ничего не работает :( Я не понимаю как мне обратиться к созданному объекту, в других функциях (кроме той, где его конструктор **Plant newPlant = new Plant()**) чтобы изменить значения переменных.

А метод **ShowInfo** Вообще пишет что **infoBlock** не существует в ее контексте.( что конечно же логично, но как тогда делать )

Помогите пожалуйста.
Исходник: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F0eADjJtHDpiW64SGSzptgzRZv324YHS/view?usp=sharing

```
namespace plant
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool day = false;
        string color, name;
        int age;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();     
        }

        void plant1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(plantName.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Введите название растения");
            }
            else
            {
                if (color != null)
                {
                    Plant newPlant = new Plant();
                    newPlant.name = plantName.Text;
                    newPlant.color = color;
                    newPlant.age = 0;
                    switch (color)
                    {
                        case "red":
                            //plantImage.Source = ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage(Properties.Resources.redPlant);
                            break;
                        case "green":
                            //plantImage.Source = ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage(Properties.Resources.greenPlant);
                            break;
                        case "yellow":
                            //plantImage.Source = ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage(Properties.Resources.yellowPlant);
                            break;
                    }
                    //garden.Source = ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage(Properties.Resources.garden);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Выберите цвет");
                }
            }}}}
```

Класс Plant

```
namespace plant
{
    internal class Plant
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
        public string color;

        public void ShowInfo()
        {
            infoBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Информация о растении:"));
            infoBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Имя:"));
            infoBlock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(newPlant.name)));
            infoBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Цвет:"));
            infoBlock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(newPlant.color)));
            infoBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Возраст:"));
            infoBlock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(Convert.ToString(newPlant.age))));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как использувать переменные одной формы в другой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835214/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: 1) Нет такого понятия, как `главный код` 2) `Но ничего не работает` - это ничего не объясняет 3) читайте про области видимости переменных и полей

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обратиться к экземпляру класса, в другой функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1263541/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)