# Как обратиться к экземпляру класса, в другой функции?

Tags: c#, wpf

В функции которая обрабатывает клик по кнопке я создаю экземпляр **newPlant**  класса **Plant**

```
Plant newPlant = new Plant()
{
   name = plantName.Text,
   color = color,
   age = 316
};
```

Как мне обратиться к этому экземпляру в другой функции, чтобы поменять значения полей и вызвать метод класса?
Когда я пытаюсь писать через **newPlant**, пишет что такого имени не существует в данном контексте.

Comment: Например, передать в функцию экземпляр этого объекта.
public void DoSomthing(Plant plant){
   plant.name = "...";
}

Comment: @Игорь Пишет: Нет перегруженного метода для "showInfo_Click", который соответствует делегату "RoutedEventHandler"

Comment: сделать `Plant newPlant` приватным полем класса в котором расположены эти функции, а точнее методы.

Comment: Хватит задавать одно и тоже, почитайте внимательно ссылку, что я вам даю! Хотите использовать объект в других методах внутри класса, выносите ее за пределы метода и делайте там приватное поле. Хотите использовать за пределами класса, изменяйте модификатор доступа, хотите, чтобы класс/метод использовал внешний объект, передавайте через конструктор/параметр. Об этом всем написано по ссылке, которую я вам уже 2-й вопрос подряд кидаю...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Прошу прощения, но я не понимаю как это сделать.
Вот моя задача: https://ibb.co/6mYMRLB
Если вам не трудно, можете на пальцах объяснить как это сделать в контексте моего кода.

Comment: Написать "не понимаю" легче, чем попробовать, да?) Ну ок, по порядку, строка `= new MainWindow()` что делает? Ключевое слово `new`, то есть "создать новый". Это то поведение, которое вы хотите? Далее, что не понятного в  `Хотите использовать объект в других методах внутри класса, выносите ее за пределы метода и делайте там приватное поле`? Вроде все доходчиво написал. Далее, `Хотите использовать за пределами класса, изменяйте модификатор доступа`, ну и `хотите, чтобы класс/метод использовал внешний объект, передавайте через конструктор/параметр.`, что тут не ясно? Ссылку откройте, там примеры!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ При большом уважении, я понимаю как это, когда очевидные вам вещи кажутся неочевидными и сложными для другого, но я не понимаю вас 1) что значит выносите его за пределы метода? 2) "Меняйте модификатор" доступа, везде стоит public. 3) Примеры по ссылке у меня не получается связать с моими примерами
https://ibb.co/6X8L5nf

Comment: `что значит выносите его за пределы метода?` - открываем ту ссылку, что я вам дал и видим `А сможем ли мы получить доступ MyField из других классов, методов и др.?`, далее там же видим пример, где подробно расписано `Мы задаем необходимый нам объект, к которому имеет доступ все, что находится внутри текущего класса.`. Вроде понятно все, не? Даже с примером...  Также хочу заметить, что вы меня не слышите! Я что сказал? "Ключевое слово `new`, то есть "создать новый". Вы делаете новое окно. когда вам надо передать ссылку на старое (как? Опять же в том ответе `это так называемый "конструктор",`).