# Закрытие формы по таймеру C#

Tags: c#, winforms, таймер

На первой форме при выборе определённой радиокнопки по нажатию на кнопку открывается вторая форма на некоторое время:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Код второй формы:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (form1.radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                // 1000 - 1сек. время, через которое запустится таймер и закроет форму
                timer1.Interval = 5000;
                // через 5 сек форма закроется и появиться главная. не забиваете, что мы вызвали дочернюю форму и через 5 сек её закрыли
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }

            if (form1.radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                // 1000 - 1сек. время, через которое запустится таймер и закроет форму
                timer1.Interval = 10000;
                // через 5 сек форма закроется и появиться главная. не забиваете, что мы вызвали дочернюю форму и через 5 сек её закрыли
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Не срабатывает таймер вообще, если использовать радиокнопки. Работает только если оставить так:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                // 1000 - 1сек. время, через которое запустится таймер и закроет форму
                timer1.Interval = 5000;
                // через 5 сек форма закроется и появиться главная. не забиваете, что мы вызвали дочернюю форму и через 5 сек её закрыли
                timer1.Enabled = true;
         }
```

Вот код радиокнопок из Дизайнера:

```
// 
            // radioButton1
            // 
            this.radioButton1.AutoSize = true;
            this.radioButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(358, 266);
            this.radioButton1.Name = "radioButton1";
            this.radioButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 17);
            this.radioButton1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.radioButton1.TabStop = true;
            this.radioButton1.Text = "radioButton1";
            this.radioButton1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // radioButton2
            // 
            this.radioButton2.AutoSize = true;
            this.radioButton2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(571, 266);
            this.radioButton2.Name = "radioButton2";
            this.radioButton2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 17);
            this.radioButton2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.radioButton2.TabStop = true;
            this.radioButton2.Text = "radioButton2";
            this.radioButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

Comment: `Form1 form1 = new Form1();`... Ну ведь пишете `new`, то есть **новый**... Также к чему все эти таймеры? Если надо закрыть форму спустя N сек, то `await Task.Delay(5000); Close();` будет достаточно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Попробовал Ваш вариант, не помог. Так же ничего не происходит.

Comment: Что не происходит? Я вам сказал `Form1 form1 = new Form1();`, вы делаете НОВУЮ форму, а не используете старую, а значит все ваши проверки radioButton как минимум бессмысленны.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну хорошо, а как мне во второй форме проверить, какую радиокнопку выбрал пользователь?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я сделал так: вторая форма унаследуется от первой. Тогда по нажатию на кнопку выскакивает вторая форма с точно такими же элементами и всё так же не закрывается.

Comment: `унаследуется от первой`, эм, что...? Вам тут нужно конструктор переопределить, куда вы ссылку на первую форму передадите, а не использовать "наследование".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ооооо, всё получилось, большое Вам спасибо, Евгений. Извините за глупость мою!