# Передача данных между viewmodel по кнопке

Tags: wpf, mvvm

у меня есть главное window представление Main привязана к MainVM, и есть window представление Accaunt привязана к AccauntVM как мне передать логин из AccauntVM в MainVM по кнопке?

Comment: Зачем главной VM знать что либо про данные пользователя? Ну а если хотите, то вы не знаете как передавать данные из класса в класс или что? Делаете конструктор и передаете как `new MainVM(login)`, или делаете свойство и передаете через него, ну либо делаете метод и вызываете его.

Comment: а можно маленький пример

Comment: Странно такое видеть. Вроде MVVM, а как передавать данные из класса в класс для вас прям вопрос века... Ну ок, допустим [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553).