# Как в данном случае передать значение переменной получаемой в методе одного класса в другой класс?

Tags: c#

Я пытался использовать .this и создавать экземпляр класса для обращения к filename или _audioFile как к полям класса, меняя у них модификаторы доступа, не выходит...

```
public partial class frmMainForm : Form
{

    private WaveOutEvent _outputDevice;
    private AudioFileReader _audioFile;

    public frmMainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // ОБРАБОТЧИК СОБЫТИЙ ДЛЯ КНОПКИ "OPEN"
    private void OnbuttonOpenClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {             
            try
            {
                string fileName = dialog.FileName;                 // получаем имя файла
                _audioFile = new AudioFileReader($"{fileName}");  // Читаем аудиофайл, используя расширение в названии.
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Неверный формат файла!");       // Сообщаем пользователю  обошибке, если пытается открыть неподхдящий формат.
            }
        }
    }



public class WavFileUtils 
{
    // необходимо получить filename из прошлого метода класса 
    // чтобы использовать в методе ниже
    
    private static TimeSpan GetWavFileDuration(filename)
    {
        WaveFileReader wf = new WaveFileReader(fileName);
        return wf.TotalTime;
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не тестировал, но попробуйте так

```
        private static WaveFileReader TimeSpan GetWavFileDuration(string filename)
        {
            WaveFileReader wf = new WaveFileReader(fileName);
            return wf.TotalTime;
        }
```