# Изменить свойства объекта WPF из другого класса

Tags: c#, wpf, static

У меня есть WPF окно под название WorkSpace в котором есть

`<TextBlock x:Name="TBAlert" .../>`

И есть некий класс А в котором я пытаюсь обратиться к этому текстбокс

```
 public static async Task DoAlert(string line)
    {
        WorkSpace.TBAlert.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        WorkSpace.TBAlert.Text = line;
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        WorkSpace.TBAlert.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Выдает ошибку, что для не статичного элемента требуется ссылка на объект.

П.С. Я только учусь, звучит как что то базовое) я пытался гуглить не че не нашел_) подскажите хотя бы как загуглить, если слишком базовый вопрос)

Весь Класс с этим методом, выглядит примерно так.

```
    public static void Initialize() 
    {
        WorkSpace.BaseCreateEvent += BaseCreate;
    }

    }
    static public void BaseCreate(string worker)
    {
        string line = "Создание базы данных";
        DoLog(worker, line);
    }

    static public async void DoLog(string worker, string whatHappens)
    {
        string line = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        line += " " + worker + " " + whatHappens;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("log.txt", true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
        await DoAlert(line);
    }

    public static async Task DoAlert(string line)
    {
        WorkSpace.TBAlert.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        WorkSpace.TBAlert.Text = line;
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        WorkSpace.TBAlert.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553 А вообще, у вас тут все изначально не так. Не забывайте, что WPF - это XAML и привязки, а вы почему-то игнорируете их. Ваши `= Visibility.Visible;` должны быть в XAML, а в C# должны быть лишь данные.

Comment: Не че не понял честно говоря) Решил через костыли)

Comment: Ну вот советую понять и начать изучать сразу правильный подход к разработке WPF проекта. Повторю - WPF это не WinForms, тут в первую очередь используется XAML для дизайна проекта, а также Binding для привязки дизайна к данным. У вас не должно быть в проекте `x:Name` и потом обращение в коде по имени к контролу, если вы это делаете - значит у вас проблемы.

Comment: Когда-то я писал под WPF движок тост-нотификашек. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61564124/12888024 для примера поизучайте, как оно работает, много нового узнаете.