# Как обновить свойство привязки WPF из другого класса?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, c#-8.0

Есть вот такое свойство для MainWindow

```
 internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
    #region Статус состояния
    
    private string _Status;
    /// <summary>
    /// состояние программы
    /// </summary>
    public string Status
    {
        get => _Status;
        set=>Set(ref _Status, value);   
    }
    #endregion
 }
```

которое привязано к textbox

```
<TextBlock  x:Name="statusTxt"   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="630"  Height="50"  Text="{Binding Status}" />
```

Собственно структура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и сам класс viewmodel

```
 internal abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName=null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        if(Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Как я могу поменять значение свойства из класса никак не связанного с mainwindow?

В MainWindowViewModel создал следующую функцию

```
public void sta(MainWindowViewModel mv,string ss)
    {
       mv._Status= ss;           
    }
```

и вызываю ее из другого класса

```
MainWindowViewModel mwvm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        mwvm.sta(mwvm, "new status");
```

Comment: А как вы такое реализовали, если бы не было WPF, например, простое консольное приложение и два класса? Наверно `var second = new SecondClass(this);` ... `class SecondClass { public SecondClass(MainViewModel mainVm){ mainVm.Status="New Status"; } }`, верно? Ну так почему тут у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ свойство то поменяется, но вьюшка об этом не узнает

Comment: Почему? У вас INPC настроен, все в этом плане хорошо. Если один экземпляр класса будет (а у вас должен быть он всегда один), то и обновлять все должно. Передача экземпляра класса в класс - это стандарт, который у всех вдруг работает, а у вас нет)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я только начал изучать mvvm,  я попробовал передать экземпляр(добавил в вопросе), но все равно во вью значение не меняется

Comment: Прочитайте еще раз, то, что я написал выше, внимательно! Я вам что сказал? `Если один экземпляр класса`, также какой пример кода показал? `new SecondClass(this)` и `public SecondClass(MainViewModel mainVm){ mainVm.Status="New Status"; }`, то есть, передача объекта идет через конструктор класса. А теперь смотрим на ваш код, что видим? `MainWindowViewModel mwvm = new MainWindowViewModel();` (создать новый класс), `mwvm.sta(mwvm, "new status");` (вызвать из этого НОВОГО класса метод). Тут не MVVM и WPF, тут простая работа с классами. Почитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553).

Answer (score 0):

Сделано как учит Павел Ш. на Ютубе))) Я тоже так делаю). Отталкиваетесь от того, что у вас должен быть один экземпляр VM. Поэтому либо реализовать паттерн singletone, и обращаться из любого места к классу VM и его свойствам. Либо реализовать инверсию управления, внедрение зависимостей и из DI контейнера получать экземпляр VM и с ним работать.