# Не добавляются данные в свойства класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Winfows-Forms, на форме две кнопки (одна для записи, другая для чтения) И 3 текстбокса

```
namespace test
{
    public class Testing
    {
        public Testing()
        {
        }
 
        public Testing(string name, string age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }
 
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Далее добавляю данные и пробую загрузить их из свойства класса, но данные не выводятся

```
namespace test
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Testing ts = new Testing
            {
                Name = textBox1.Text,
                Age = textBox2.Text
            };
        }
 
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Testing ts = new Testing();
            textBox3.Text += $"{ts.Name + ts.Age}";
        }
    }
}
```

Это глюк или я что-то не так делаю? (Забыл уже)...

Comment: Переведите слово `new`, что означает? "Новый", да? Ну а теперь смотрим, например на `new Testing()`, что означает? "Создать новый объект типа `Testing`. Ну раз он новый, то почему в нем должны быть старые данные? Создайте объект один раз и вынесите его за пределы методов, с ним уже и работайте.

Comment: Вижу тут фундаментальную ошибку: "пробую загрузить их из свойства класса". Свойства класса не содержат никаких данных, так как класс - это всего лишь описание данных и методов, с ними связанных. А в программе создаются объекты каких-то классов, и в них уже хранятся данные. Создали объект, сохранили в нём данные - из этого же самого объекта и надо эти данные читать.

Comment: А как мне тогда инициализировать класс Testing и в него добавлять данные если он не `static` или же можно просто сделать его статичным и обращаться от любого класса, как лучше?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а почему он не имеет никаких видимых геттеров и сеттеров?

Comment: @ZuPooSwitch https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/197075/220553

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace test
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Testing ts;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ts = new Testing();
            ts.Name = textBox1.Text;
            ts.Age = textBox2.Text;
        }
 
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.Text += $"{ts.Name + ts.Age}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).