# Как задать ивент на свертывание окна через страницы в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Итак, у меня есть страница, в которой я сделал кнопку свертывания и хочу привязать к нему ивент. Если бы это было окно, я бы сделал так:

```
WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

Но через страницу, конечно, это не работает. Я пытался сделать так:

```
(this.Parent as Window).WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
```

Это крашит программу при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку.
Как это можно реализовать? Я могу как-нибудь через объект Page ссылаться на Window?

Comment: При чем тут "ивент"? Ваш вопрос совершенно не связан с этим механизмом. Вообще, ваш вопрос на тему [передачи объектов из класса в класс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553), но в WPF то, что вы делаете не принято, ибо WPF это в первую очередь привязки и XAML, вы не должны хотеть вообще в коде делать `контрол.Свойство = значение` (в вашем случае `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;`), это должно быть в XAML, а в C# должны быть лишь данные, простые классы и свойства. Другими словами, ваш проект должен работать даже тогда, когда вы удалите все в XAML, без вывода ошибок.

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;` А архитектура на базе Frame/Page это жестоко https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567. Ещё про MVVM что-нибудь почитайте.

Comment: Благодарю! MVVM еще буду изучать, но пока надо проект добить.