# Метод в точке входа не видит входных данных

Tags: c#

Хочу понять как работает обращение методов внутри класса. Т.е. хочу разобраться как один метод может получать  некоторые значения у другого и далее выводить это все в итоговом методе который инициализирую в точке старта.
Проблема следующая: метод в точке старта просто не видит входных значений...

Сам код:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Calc
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ResultOfNums();
        }

        public static void Nums()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите высоту");
            string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
            int height = Convert.ToInt32(num1);

            Console.WriteLine("Введите ширину");
            string num2 = Console.ReadLine();
            int width = Convert.ToInt32(num2);
        }

        public static int ResultOfNums(int height, int width)
        {
            int area = height * width;
            Console.WriteLine(area);
            return area;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Когда вы пишете `ResultOfNums(что-то)`, то вот это "что-то" должно быть **обязательно** задано при вызове, вы в методе `Main` вызвали, но обязательные аргументы не передали. Теперь касательно переменных, тут все просто, вот что **создается** внутри `{ ... }`, то и используется только внутри, что задается **за** пределами, то и используется за пределами. У вас переменные создаются в методе `Nums`, они локальные, доступны только **в этом методе**, если хотите их за пределами использовать, вынесите их за `{...}`. Ну и на тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю за ответ! :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ во

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема вашего кода в том, что вы вызываете метод `ResultOfNums` не передав в него нужных аргументов (длину и ширину).

Метод `Nums()`, который должен получать эти значения у пользователя - нигде не вызывается.

Чтобы код работал правильно - должна быть правильная последовательность выполнения:

1. Запуск программы из точки входа (`Main`).
2. Сбор ввода пользователя (`Nums`).
3. Вычисление результата (`ResultOfNums`).

В вашем случае, чтобы получить в методе `ResultOfNums` нужные значения - вы, во-первых, сперва должны вызывать метод ввода.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Nums();
}
```

Теперь, при запуске программы - вы увидите сообщения о вводе высоты и ширины из метода `Nums()`.

Затем, когда данные будут введены - вы должны вызвать метод `ResultOfNums`, указав ему как аргументы - введённые числа.

Сделать это удобнее всего из метода Nums():

```
public static void Nums()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите высоту");
    string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(num1);

    Console.WriteLine("Введите ширину");
    string num2 = Console.ReadLine();
    int width = Convert.ToInt32(num2);
    
    var area = ResultOfNums(height, width)
}
```

Что даст итоговый код вида:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Calc
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Вызываем диалог с пользователем
            Nums();
        }
        
        public static void Nums()
        {
            // Определяем значение высоты
            Console.WriteLine("Введите высоту");
            string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
            int height = Convert.ToInt32(num1);

            // Определяем значение ширины
            Console.WriteLine("Введите ширину");
            string num2 = Console.ReadLine();
            int width = Convert.ToInt32(num2);

            // Имея значения от пользователя - вызываем подсчёт результата.
            // Обратите внимание - этот метод будет вызван только после того, 
            // как была выполнена прошлая часть кода
            var area = ResultOfNums(height, width); 
        }

        public static int ResultOfNums(int height, int width)
        {
            int area = height * width;
            Console.WriteLine(area);
            return area;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У человека явное недопонимание того, как работают переменные, их видимость, доступность. Автор ожидал того, что раз он в одном методе написал `int height = Convert.ToInt32(num1);`, значит и в другом методе он может получить доступ к этой переменной. Ваш ответ конечно решает проблему, да, но не объясняет что, почему, и как, из-за чего для автора вопроса он будет по сути, бесполезным.