# Как изменит текст лейбеля через текстбокс на си№

Tags: c#-7.0

Извините  я новичок на си# у меня ест 2 формы 1 ест лейбл как изменить текст лейбелa через текc бокс  находятся другой форме но текст лейбла не изменяется вы можете мне помочь

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm frm = new frm();
        Form5 form5 = new Form5();
        if (bunifuTextBox1.Text == frm.label5.Text)
        {
            frm.label5.Text = null;
            bunifuTextBox1.Text = frm.label5.Text;
        }
       
        

    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553

Comment: наверное вместо == надо написать !=