# Передача данных из одного метода в другой

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет) Я студент 1 курса потихоньку учу C# и решил попробовать себя в Windows Forms.
Не бейте сильно правда могу тупить.
Суть вопроса: я при нажатии кнопки 1 создаю лист, а в кнопке 2 я бы хотел, чтобы при условии существования этого листа у меня шло например перечисление обьектов в нём, да впринципе что угодно, я хочу чтобы в метод 2-ой кнопки вставились данные из метода 1-ой кнопки.

```
namespace TESTWPF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
            list.Add(new Person("David", 18));
            list.Add(new Person("Elizaveta", 18));
            MessageBox.Show("Лист создан!");
        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // вот тут хочу сделать перечисление листа(из 1 метода)

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553

Comment: Спасибо) Вроде бы разобрался