# C# WinForms Обновление формы, после добавления данных из другой

Tags: c#, winforms

Ребят, помогите решить проблему, у меня есть Form1(основная) и есть Form2(форма, связанная с поиском. Поиск идет по полю, по одному значению). Задача: Найденную строку по полю вывести в textBoxы на Form1(основную) не что-бы добавлялась новая форма уже с добавленными данными, а это форма обновила данные.

```
private Form1 Form1;
public Search(Form1 form1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form1 = form1;
}
Form1 = new Form1();
Search search = new Search(Form1);
Form1.textBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0);
Form1.textBox2.Text = reader.GetString(1);
Form1.textBox3.Text = reader.GetString(2);
Form1.textBox4.Text = reader.GetString(3);
Form1.listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(4));
this.Close();
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ С этим все вроде бы понятно, меня больше интересует вопрос как обновить, а не получить вторую form1 с заполненными данными

Comment: В чем проблема получить нужную форму и написать в нужном методе `форма.Свойство = новоеЗначение;`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Создал я например экземпляр формы form1.textBox1.text = "hello world". Событие разумеется по кнопке, запускаю приложение, код запустился действие выполнил, вывод на form1 нет никакого, добавил form1.show(); запустил код, помимо формы, на которой ничего не отображается, выводит форму на которой в итоге отображается, но что делать с формой на которой не отображается, она как главная форма?

Comment: 1. Не объясняйте код словами, пожалуйста. Под вопросом кнопка "Править", жмете, добавляете все туда. 2. Если у вас нужна форма не меняет данные, но после `Show()` вдруг все там есть, значит вы **не передаете ссылку** (как я вам писал выше), а создаете **новую форму** при помощи `new Form1()`. Еще раз прочитайте все, что есть по ссылке выше, особенно то, что идет после `Теперь поговорим о передаче значений между классами:`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Добавил код в вопрос. Можете подсказать где ошибка?

Comment: Не вставляйте код в комментарии, его там невозможно читать. Перенес код в вопрос, отредактировал комментарий. _Можете подсказать где ошибка_ - как вы поняли, что там ошибка? Студия вам не говорит, где ошибка?

Comment: Я ведь вам прямым текстом сказал выше `а создаете новую форму при помощи new Form1()`. Неужели это не понятно? Ну вот смотрим ваш код, видим `Form1 = new Form1(); Search search = new Search(Form1);`... Еще раз, вы должны передавать **ссылку** на нужную форму, а не создавать ее по новой. Допустим, если это все в коде первой формы, то `new Search(this)`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ приведите пожалуйста максимально простой пример с получением ссылки из формы, потому что читая вашу статью, вызывали вы именно так `Form1 = new Form1();`

Comment: Еще раз перечитайте комментарий выше.

Comment: Я не могу понять как это правильно прописать: `new Search(this)`

Comment: Так и прописать. `this` - это текущий объект, если вы находитесь внутри класса `Form1`, то `this` - это будет именно ссылка на `Form1`. Ну а если вы в другом классе делаете `new Search(...)`, то значит вам туда надо передать сначала `this` из `Form1`, а уже эту ссылку передавать в инициализацию `Search()`.

Comment: Все, я разобрался, в форме 2 создаем переменные, в которых будем хранить ссылки, в форме 1 инициализируем форму 2. Перед открытием окна мы в переменные забрасываем ссылки на компоненты формы, после чего к ним в другой форме присваиваем значение. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Зачем вам переменные, когда это должен быть конструктор, ибо без этих "форм" ваш код работать не будет... Тоже самое, только `new Search(то, что передаете в переменные);`, что в этом сложного я не пойму) Вы хотяб общались со мной, а не просто просили бы от меня код, ведь полюбому ловите ошибку или что-то еще, о чем молчите и что в ступор вас вводит.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я разобрался, я при открытии формы передаю ссылку на другую форму `Form2 frm = new Form2(); frm.but1 = this.button1; frm.ShowDialog();` а вот эта переменная у будет хранить ссылку на элемент другой формы `public TextBox text1` . После чего я обращаюсь к этой переменной и у меня все передается