# Смена цвета кнопки №1 по нажатию кнопки №2 в другой форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две формы .cs. В каждой есть кнопка. В Form1.cs есть кнопка button_1, в 2.cs button_2

Код 1.cs:

```cs
namespace fn
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void loadform(object Form)
        {
            if (this.mainpanel.Controls.Count > 0)
                this.mainpanel.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
            Form f = Form as Form;
            f.TopLevel = false;
            f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.mainpanel.Controls.Add(f);
            this.mainpanel.Tag = f;
            f.Show();
        }

        private void btn_switch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadform(new _2());
        }
    }
}
```

Код 2.cs:

```cs
namespace fn
{
    public partial class _2 : Form
    {
        public _2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button_1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            button_2.BackColor = button_1.BackColor;    
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача состоит в том, что мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки button_1 в форме 2.cs, кнопка button_2 в форме Form1.cs меняла цвет на такой же

Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, покажите код, про который говорите. Названия в тексте похожи на шифр, ничего непонятно. Какая задача решается? Об этом тоже напишите в вопросе.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xNv_2hLLYnYZUoalKQGtSGAM5ABgR0K9/view?usp=sharing - проект c# winform

https://imgur.com/a/VZeRZWu - скрины проекта + код


Есть две формы .cs. В каждой есть кнопка. В 1.cs есть кнопка button1, в 2.cs button2
При нажатии на button 2 выполняется  
{button2.BackColor = Color.Green; 
button1.BackColor = button2.BackColor}

Если же первая строка выполняется и цвет кнопки меняется, вторая - нет

Comment: Отредактируйте сам вопрос. И код прямо в вопрос текстом - [edit]

Comment: Сделал, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где-то уже был такой же вопрос и ответ на него, потому что проблема тривиальная. Но сходу не нашел, поэтому покажу. Вам стоит поизучать основы ООП, тогда текущая задача станет лёгкой.

Делаем публичный метод, меняющий цвет кнопки в первой форме

```
public void SetButtonColor(Color color)
{
    button_1.BackColor = color;
}
```

Передаем ссылку на первую форму в конструктор второй формы

```
private void btn_switch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadform(new _2(this));
}
```

Принимаем ссылку в конструкторе

```
private Form form1;

public Form1(Form form)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form1 = form;
}
```

Теперь просто можно вызвать тот самый метод

```
private void button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button_2.BackColor = Color.Green;
    form1.SetButtonColor(button_2.BackColor);
}
```

Готово, если я правильно понял задачу.

Вы не заметили один нюанс, у вас `button_1` есть в обеих формах. Разберитесь с этим.

Comment: Большое спасибо!